# scrolling inside the screen command

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I am trying to use screen command in Ubuntu. While the basic functionality works fine, I am having trouble while scrolling when I use split window functionality. 
Here is the scr file I created.

```
screen -t "SysLog Monitor" 1 tail -f /var/log/syslog
screen -t "Cli Window" 2 bash
split
select 1
focus
select 2
startup_message off
```

When I go to the syslog monitor window, scrolling does not work. This works fine in Redhat based servers. Are there different commands for Ubuntu?